# C# WPF Select UserControl on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, canvas, itemscontrol

I have a Canvas with custom UserControls in it. Now I want to be able to have them selectable since I want to have a properties box which shows information about that specific item. What would be nice would be to have something along the way of when I click on a UserControl in the Canvas a **SelectedItem** property could be set to the viewmodel of that usercontrol or something better. I just have no clue how to do it good nor have I been successful in making it work in any way that why i'm asking here.

Currently I have a DocumentViewModel which holds information about the open document/project. In this viewmodel I have a list of components, which are the ones being represented on the canvas. This looks something like this:

```
public class DocumentViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
        private ObservableCollection<ComponentViewModel> components;
        public ObservableCollection<ComponentViewModel> Components
        {
            get { return components; }
        }

        private string filePath;
        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return filePath; }
            set { filePath = value; }
        }

    ...
}
```

Then I have a DataTemplate for how the DocumentViewModel should look in the View. This looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DocumentViewModel}">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Converters:GuiSizeConverter x:Key="SizeConverter"/>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Height="{Binding CurrentProject.Height, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}"
                            Width="{Binding CurrentProject.Width, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameColorKey}}"/>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Utils:DraggableExtender.CanDrag" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter},Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The ComponentViewModel is a base class for my component ViewModels which are simple wrappers around my Model objects. The I use DataTemplates to bind them to a View so nothing special there.

So does anyone have any good suggestions for how to make these controls clickable so i can detect which one is selected so i can bind that to a properties box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `ItemsControl` just use a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx), which has selection.

Comment: Haha, that simple. Thanks alot for the help, worked like a charm.

Comment: It is indeed, glad it helped :)

Comment: One thing i noticed though when changing over to ListBox is that my dragging seems to work really crappy. For instance if I move the mouse to fast and the pointer gets outside the control it stops and i cant move mouse outside canvas while dragging. Any idea what is different between ItemsControl and ListBox when it comes to that?

Comment: I don't know, sorry; i never used those controls in combination with dragging and the like.